# Make sql queries on Odoo data

Tags: python, orm, odoo

I want to make simple SQL queries on Odoo collections.

While it's easy to use the explicit mode of Odoo to retrieve data:

```py
from xmlrpc import client
from root import OD_URL 
from root import OD_DB
from root import OD_USERNAME
from root import OD_PASSWORD
common = client.ServerProxy(f'{OD_URL}/xmlrpc/2/common')
models = client.ServerProxy(f'{OD_URL}/xmlrpc/2/object')
user_connection = common.authenticate(OD_DB, OD_USERNAME, OD_PASSWORD, {})
ids = models.execute_kw(OD_DB, user_connection, OD_PASSWORD, table_name, "search",
                                    [[

                                ]]
                            )
```

I don't find any decent tutorial for the implicit method (with sql queries). 
I see explanations like this one:

```py
# retrieve data from product_product
result = self._cr.execute('select * from product_product')
```

or:

```
from openerp.osv import fields, orm, osv

class AccountVoucher(orm.Model):

    def _get_selection(self, cr, uid, context):

        partner = context.get('id_partner',[])
        cr.execute("""SELECT num_bl FROM stock_picking WHERE state='done' and invoice_state='2binvoiced' and partner_id= %d""",(partner,))

        return cr.fetchall()
```

but once again, I don't see where openerp module comes from, etc.

thanks a lot for your help

Comment: which odoo version are you using?

Comment: The version is Odoo 13

Comment: Check Odoo ORM?